# 4g router not working after powering it with a 12V battery

Tags: batteries, router

I needed to power a Huawei router with a 12V power supply as this will be living in my garage where there is no power available.

My current setup is a 12V car battery hooked up to a small fuse box. I'm currently powering an EZVIZ camera with this setup with no issues and I've also got a USB cable hooked to the fuse box via a buck converter - also with no issues. All fuses in the fusebox are rated at 10A.

I tested the router in the house first with the original power supply which is rated at 12V, 1A.

I then tested it with another power supply I had lying around with the same specifications and the router ran fine again. I used this spare power supply to cut the cable off so I can wire it to the mini fusebox I have connected to the car battery. I double checked the polarity of the original power supply and made sure the cable I wired in the fuse box matched before plugging in the router.

The moment I connected up the router, it started up for a second and then powered off. It now doesn't power on at all, even in the house with the original power supply.

The car battery is currently charged at 12.5V.

I opened up the router and everything looks fine, no blown resistors etc. There are 7 controllers on the board though that I cannot tell if they're fine just by appearance.

After the failure, I tested the original power supply and the output was 11.98v. Could the slight overvoltage of 12.5V from the car battery have damaged the router?

EDIT: I found that culprit. 2 micro chips under one of the covers have blown. these were directly above the barrel connector. I can only assume that the slight overvoltage was the blame!

If anyone has any other theories, please share them.

I'll be ordering a new router which will be fed via regulator to keep the voltage constant at 12v. I hope that works!

Comment: That's truly weird, but product usage/repair questions are not on topic here.  Worth noting too that this battery probably isn't going to give you much runtime.

Comment: i have a solar panel to keep the battery topped up during the day. By the way, i tried this without the solar panel connected so no doubts of any surges from the panel.

Comment: "These were directly above the barrel connector..." Could it be the DC plug wobbled, touching those parts?  Another possibility - connected backwards to battery.

Comment: i checked the polarity as i already stated. the barrel connector is firmly soldered in place